# Merging layers with preferences or ranks using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, merge, mosaic, union

I want to make a "Mosaic" or a "Compilation" of 20  shp. layers which some of them are overlap. The layers has a field named "Year" and I want the newest be on top and delete the overlap older shps data "under" it.
I didn't find Union or Merge tools helpful because the union do not delete overlap data, (I ranked it) and the merge tool make it random.

Is there any option to merge the layer but with ranks or preferences?

Answer (score 1):

Union should work. Then add a maxYear-field and calculate as max of all other year fields, for example using arcpy. Will not be ideal if you have other fields but year in the features.

[image]
[image]

Union all SHAPEs then adapt and execute code in Python window:

```py
import arcpy

fc = 'poly1_Union1' #Change

yearfields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc) if f.name.startswith('Year')] #Im assuming your year field starts with 'Year'

newfield = 'maxYear' #Change namd if you want

arcpy.AddField_management(fc,newfield,'LONG')

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,yearfields+[newfield]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[-1] = max(row)
        cursor.updateRow(row)

#arcpy.DeleteField_management(fc, yearfields) #Uncomment if you want to delete all the year fields
```

Comment: If you have the Advanced version of ArcGIS you could also run a series of update overlays.  You could use model builder to do it.

Comment: @Johns ok! You could post that as an answer

Comment: This isn't really an answer but an example to suggest one.  The layers I use in this script naturally sort in the order I want them to be used.